# Copy Firefox bookmarks names not URL

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Is there any way to copy bookmarks name in firefox? Regular copy just copy the URL alone, I want to be able to copy Names too

Answer (score 0):

Just go to

> **Firefox >Bookmarks > Show all bookmarks > Import and backup > Export Bookmarks to HTML**

after that it will be exported in a html file. then Import that html file where you want to copy all Bookmarks.

> **Firefox >Bookmarks > Show all bookmarks > Import and backup > Import Bookmarks from HTML**

I am sure your problem will be solved.

Comment: I am afraid this isn't my problem..... I am not wanting to export bookmarks, I want to extract "Names" of group of bookmarks to clipboard

Comment: this process will copy both name and urls

Comment: I want to copy Names to clipboard and using them in spreadsheet not for firefox

Comment: then open exported html file using Mozilla or chrome and simply copy and paste in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

- Export Firefox (v76.0) bookmarks as html
- Run `grep -o -E "\">.+</A>" bookmarks.html > bookmark_names.txt` in the terminal
- Then you can remove the leading and trailing characters in a text editor: `^">` and `</A>$`

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on a bookmark in FF's sidebar, you get a "Properties" item
in the resulting menu. Click on that, and you get a dialog with the bookmark
name in a text box (selected automatically), which can be copied as usual.

Answer (score 0):

tabinfo copy chrome extension worked.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabinfocopy/micdllihgoppmejpecmkilggmaagfdmb

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1162199)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/513819)